# Creating a list with different colors

Tags: android, user-interface

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q97Zt.png)

Hello guys i am trying to make one app.i know the basics in android and i am still learning.I want my UI to look something similar to the image attached. i am confused at how to design this UI in android.What i mean is the list in the UI has different colors at each item and that too its gradient color scheme and how to make these list item expandable such that whenever someone click on one item it will expand will show the menu with some button in it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post the code you have and I can help you modify it. I would be helpful to know if you have a fixed number of rows in your ListView and what colors you want to use.

Comment: Thanks a lot but i have done it own my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213789/android-custom-listview-each-row-different-colours) hope help : (example with ListView)

```
public getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_xml, null);
   do some stuff...

   //let say you have an arraylist of color
   convertView.setBackgroundColor(arraylist.get(position));

   //in case that your color is limited, just re-use your color again
     and some logic how to re-use the colors.}
```